# Bitrix Импорт каталога через cron. Не получаю сообщения об ошибке

Tags: битрикс, интернет-магазин, импорт

Итак. Есть csv-файл. Специально с ошибкой. При ручном импорте через профиль показываются ошибки вида "неправильный раздел".
При настройке через cron - импорт отрабатывается, ошибочная строка не импортируется. Но в лог ничего не пишется.
Ответов в сети не нашел.

Comment: Возможно кодом не предусмотрено выводить в логи ошибки, а только выводить "на экран" и на экран выводится, но в пустоту, поэтому и не видно ошибок.

Comment: Ну как бы странно, что они предлагают достаточно удобно положить в крон или агент, но не выводят ошибок в лог.
На самом деле в /bitrix/modules/catalog/load_import/csv_new_run.php в конец положил:
if ($strImportErrorMessage<>'')
{
 echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
 echo $strImportErrorMessage;
}
и сразу стал в log-файл писать. Но при этом перезаписывает, надо делать локально на сайте (чтобы при обновлении не затиралось)+отправка лога на почту. Но вообще странно, проблема, судя по постам, с 2012 года точно.